# Android 'create table if not exist' error in Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sqlite

I'm creating an application to input input string values from EditText into a SQLite database. When running the app through the simulator, a logcat error message is received when the database will be created initially. The logcat error message is below.

01-23 16:47:39.613: E/Database(1386): Failure 1 (near "existinfoTable": syntax error) on 0x1392b8 when preparing 'create table if not existinfoTable(_idinterger primary key,sNametext not null,wUrltext not null,uNametext not null,pWordtext not null);'.

The OnCreate method it is referring to is below. I'm not sure what syntax error is causing the problem. any help would be appreciated.

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String sqlDataStore = "create table if not exist" +
        TABLE_NAME_INFOTABLE + "("+ BaseColumns._ID + "interger primary key autoincrement,"
        + COLUMN_NAME_SITE + "text not null,"
        + COLUMN_NAME_ADDRESS + "text not null,"
        + COLUMN_NAME_USERNAME + "text not null,"
        + COLUMN_NAME_PASSWORD + "text not null),";
    db.execSQL(sqlDataStore);
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the looks of it, you mispelled 'integer' and it looks like you need a spaces before 'integer', after 'exist' (I think it should be 'exists') and before '('. So....

```
String sqlDataStore = "create table if not exists " +
        TABLE_NAME_INFOTABLE + " ("+ BaseColumns._ID + " integer primary key autoincrement,"
                + COLUMN_NAME_SITE + "text not null,"
                + COLUMN_NAME_ADDRESS + "text not null,"
                + COLUMN_NAME_USERNAME + "text not null,"
                + COLUMN_NAME_PASSWORD + "text not null)";
```

You can also omit the ',' or ';' at the end of the statement.

Comment: Also needs a space before each `text not null`

Comment: Thank for catching those but I still get the same error. Here is a copy of my logcat.

Comment: 01-23 18:43:03.017: E/AndroidRuntime(1578): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "exist": syntax error: create table if not exist infoTable(_idinteger primary key autoincrement,sName text not null,wUrl text not null,uName text not null,pWord text not null),
01-23 18:43:03.017: E/AndroidRuntime(1578):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.native_execSQL(Native Method)
01-23 18:43:03.017: E/AndroidRuntime(1578):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1610)

Comment: Judging from the error, it looks like the only change you made was to correct the spelling of 'integer' and add a space before 'text'. It's kind of subtle but notice how in my answer there are spaces in some of the quotations. I was able to create the table in a test database and the only thing you need to fix is to change 'exist' to 'exists' and to add a space between '_id' and 'integer'

Comment: Truly Amazing!!!...cant believe I missed that. Its the little things that have the biggest impact. Thank YOU!!!!