# run time error while executing sqlite

Tags: android, database, sqlite

getting error `04-12 08:38:33.943: E/Database(441): Failure 1 (near "Table": syntax error) on 0x341088 when preparing 'CREATE TABLE Table (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,location_name TEXT NOT NULL,longi TEXT NOT NULL,lati TEXT NOT NULL);'.`
i followed [Android 'create table if not exist' error in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9236904/android-create-table-if-not-exist-error-in-eclipse?answertab=active#tab-top)  but still same error
my table code as follows

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" +
                        KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," +
                        KEY_LOCATION + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
                        KEY_LONGI + " TEXT NOT NULL," + KEY_LATI + " TEXT NOT NULL);"
                );
```

Comment: madhumita your query is wrong first try it in `SQLITE BROWSER`...and check there

Comment: CREATE TABLE "samirmangroliya" (" +
                        KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," +
                        KEY_LOCATION + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
                        KEY_LONGI + " TEXT NOT NULL," + KEY_LATI + " TEXT NOT NULL).

Comment: @SamirMangroliya thanks..can you please elaborate ?

Comment: madhumita its work nice in sqlite browser so try to print your query in logcat and check in sqlite browser its ok~

Comment: @SamirMangroliya please help me on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10186337/nullpointer-exception-proximity-alert

Comment: i am going to sleep now....meet you tomorrow...and comment me again..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TABLE` is a [reserved word](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html) in SQLite, so you can't name your table `Table` without escaping it or renaming it.

Comment: my table name is DATABASE_TABLE

Comment: No, it's not. that's just a variable you're concatenating. Look at the error message, it clearly shows your tablename is `Table` (`CREATE TABLE Table ...`).

Comment: No, it's not, unless you've completely gone against all conventions.  An all capitalized variable like that is used to indicate a constant.

Comment: well, either way, the table name is not `DATABASE_TABLE`, since there's clearly a concatenation operation occuring.

Comment: Stupid phone slowing me down.  As Marc said, that is not the table name.

Comment: @MarcB please help me on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10186337/nullpointer-exception-proximity-alert

Comment: @Barak please help me on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10186337/nullpointer-exception-proximity-alert